# GO Lang Unable to get XML header in response

Tags: mysql, xml, go, unmarshalling

I have a xml stored in db which i am unmarshalling using xml.unmarshall in GO with the struct I defined.
When getting the API response I am not getting the XML header and also the namespace.

```
type Entity struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name `xml:"entity" json:"-"`
etc..
    }
```

while sending response

```
func get(c *gin.Context) {

...

entity=new(model.Entity)
offeredContentTypes := []string{"application/xml", "application/json"}
    c.Negotiate(http.StatusOK, gin.Negotiate{
        Offered:  offeredContentTypes,
        XMLData:  entity,
        JSONData: entity,
    })
}
```

the xml entity I have in db has the required header as well as namespace

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><entity xmlns:ns2="http://abc/xyz">....</entity>
```

this is the type of response I get

```
<entity>...</entity>
```

How can I fix this so that i get both xml header as well as namespace??

Answer (score 0):

declare to want to use a middleware

```
router := gin.Default()

router.Use(XMLHeadergo())
```

and this is the middleware code

```
func XMLHeadergo() gin.HandlerFunc {
      return func(c *gin.Context) {
          if c.NegotiateFormat(gin.MIMEXML) == gin.MIMEXML {
              c.Writer.Write([]byte(xml.Header))
          }
          c.Next()
      }
  }
```

this prepends

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

to each responses if they are in xml format

> I ensure to output xml using gin's context function `c.XML()`

### Tip

Add a check on response length before append xml header.
This allows to send response body, if needed

```
// To Force gin to emit xml declaration before xml output
func XMLHeadergo() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {

        contentLength := c.Writer.Size()

        if c.NegotiateFormat(gin.MIMEXML) == gin.MIMEXML && contentLength >0 {
            c.Writer.Write([]byte(xml.Header))
        }
        c.Next()
    }
}
```